# Warning: Undefined variable $calculoAlcool in C:\Users\alfac\OneDrive\Documentos\instalar Xampp\htdocs\calculo.php on line 15

Tags: php, formulário

Estou tendo problemas com as variáveis do php. Defini os valores das variáveis mas quando tento executar, para a primeira variável o resultado aparece mas para as outras não. o resultado é este: O Total da gasolina vai custar 296.66666666667 MZN

> Warning: Undefined variable $calculoAlcool in C:\Users\alfac\OneDrive\Documentos\instalar Xampp\htdocs\calculo.php on line 15
> O Total do Álcool custa MZN

> Warning: Undefined variable $caluloDiezel in C:\Users\alfac\OneDrive\Documentos\instalar Xampp\htdocs\calculo.php on line 16
> O Total do diezel vai cusatr MZN

Sou iniciante, alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

Meus códigos em arquivos separados:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="calculo.php" method="POST">
    <label>Distácia em Km</label>
    <input type="text" name="distancia"/>

    <label>Autonomia</label>
    <input type="text" name="autonomia" />

    <button class="botao" type= 'submit'>enviar</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
    $distancia = $_POST['distancia'];
    $autonomia = $_POST['autonomia'];
    
    $valorGazolina = 89; 
    $valorAlcool = 450.60;
    $valorDiezel = 65.80;
    
    $calculoGazolina = ( $distancia / $autonomia ) * $valorGazolina;
    $caculoAlcool= ( $distancia / $autonomia ) * $valorAlcool;
    $calculoDiezel= ( $distancia / $autonomia ) * $valorDiezel;
    
    echo "<p>O Total da gasolina vai custar ".$calculoGazolina." MZN </p>";
    echo "<p>O Total do Álcool custa ".$calculoAlcool." MZN </p>";
    echo "<p>O Total do diezel vai cusatr ".$caluloDiezel." MZN </p>";
    ?>
```

Comment: você escreveu "caculo" num lugar, "calulo" em outro...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Primeiramente, ao adicionar código na sua pergunta, faça isso entre o marcador ```` ``` ````, e formate ele de maneira que seja de fácil entendimento (o código na sua pergunta está uma verdadeira bagunça na verdade).

O problema é com a nomeação das variáveis.
Vamos lá:

```php
// Na linha
echo "O Total do diezel vai cusatr ".$caluloDiezel." MZN";
// Deveria ser
echo "O Total do diezel vai cusatr ".$calculoDiezel." MZN";

// E na linha
$caculoAlcool= ( $distancia / $autonomia ) * $valorAlcool;
// Deveria ser
$calculoAlcool= ( $distancia / $autonomia ) * $valorAlcool;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda .